# What does watching Star Wars in Chronological order mean?

Tags: star-wars, chronological-order

4,5,6,1,2,3 because that is the order that they were released in our universe

OR

1,2,3,4,5,6 because that is the order that the events in Star Wars happens in the Star Wars universe.

Comment: Chronological in-universe or out of universe? Both are possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about a meaning of English word. And not a clear meaning either. The answer depends 100% on what the person who says "chronological" means.

Comment: You need the context of Star Wars here because the normal meaning of chronological doesn't have this sort "ambiguity". There could also be a colloquialism for the use of this word.

Comment: You should watch it in the Praxis order: 4, 5, 6.

Answer (score 4):

Typically...

Chronological order = watching the movies following the in-universe timeline. Episodes 1,2,3,4,5,6,7.

By release date = watching the the movies in order of release. Episodes 4,5,6,1,2,3,7.

To be more specific, one should use the terms "in-universe chronological" or "chronological release date" to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: You could watch them in the SLash Order:
4-5-2-3-6-7.  Just slash away ep1 from it.

Comment: @AlessandroSanfilippo Also (and more commonly) known as the Machete Order.

Comment: @AlessandroSanfilippo That is irrelevant to the question, though.

Comment: Doesnt hurt either. I think this way, is the correct way of seeing the movies . You can also include ep1 just to see Darth Maul fight Qui Gon and Obi :D.

Comment: I do however think, if you've lived in a hole your entire life and decided that watching the entire Star Wars septet was the first thing on your agenda, then the revelation of who Vader is, is the biggest surprise within the series and would be spoiled without watching them in release order.

Comment: @Catija the fact it is irrelevant to the question is why it is a comment, and not an answer. I think it deserves a mention though.